# Vim: set GUI font inside a function

Tags: vim

I'm not sure that's right way to do this, but here's the thing. I want to switch my Vim between dark scheme and light scheme. However, the `colorscheme` is not the only thing that should be switched. I want to switch the font, and indent guides color as well. So I've came up with this function:

```
fun! DarkScheme()
  colorscheme molokai
  set gfn=Monaco\ 10
  call DarkIndentGuides()
endf
```

But when I'm using external monitor, I want my font to be bigger than 10. So I want to pass the font size as parameter. I've tried

```
fun! DarkScheme(n)
  colorscheme molokai
  set gfn="Monaco ".a:n
  " and set gfn="Monaco\ ".a:n 
  " and also set gfn=Monaco\ a:n
  call DarkIndentGuides()
endf
```

but it's not working. It ignores the font size in any of these examples. How do I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method of specifying the fontsize doesn't work for me. I use `set gfn <font>:h<size>` (e.g. `set gf=Monaco:h10`), so I'm not sure why your original function (with the hard-coded font size) works.

To use the variable in this expression, you need to use the `execute` command:

```
execute ':set gfn=Monaco:h' . a:n
```

which should do the trick.

Comment: so the final solution for me is
`execute ':set gfn=Monaco\ ' . a:n `

Comment: the syntax depends on your system. Check the help for `setting-guifont` and also lines 3466 on `options.txt`. @vrybas is probably using GTK

Comment: @sidyll that's right, I use Gvim. The `:h` thing is not working for me. So, to make it clear enough, what's your platform @Prince Goulash ?